# How to write a MySQL query to detect missing (absentee) records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am stuck with a complex MySQL query. I have following tables:

```
[employee]
id
name

[department]
id
name

[employee_department_relation]
id
employee_id
department_id

[attendance]
id
employee_id
date
```

Note: attendance will be recorded only if the employee is present at that date. No specific flag is set for abseentism.

I need to find out that, how many employees from which department were absent on a particular date.

I have done so far, following SQL, but, its not perfect:

```
SELECT A.date, 
(SELECT name FROM employee WHERE id = emp_id) AS employee,
(SELECT D.name AS dept_name
 FROM deptartment D
 INNER JOIN employee_department_relation R ON R.dept_id = D.id
 INNER JOIN employee E ON E.id = R.emp_id
 WHERE R.emp_id = A.emp_id
 ) AS dept
FROM attendance A
WHERE A.date = '2014-07-03'
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Have a go at it yourself, then ask for help. **This is not a free coding service**

Comment: What did you already try? Please post your mysql approach and then we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this changing date as you like:

```
select employee.name, department.name from employee
left join employee_department_relation r on r.employee_id = employee.id
left join department on department.id = r.department_id
where employee.id not in (
    select employee_id from attendance where date = '2014-07-28'
)
```

Comment: it works atleast for basic version. I will try it by adding more records. Thanks.